# What does Facebook benefit from its Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm just wondering, what are the pros for Facebook to just give away user information (when allowed by the user of course) to external websites?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Benefits for Facebook**

- Branding
- Customer Engagement
- Drive Web Traffic
- Reputation Management
- New Customer Acquisition
- Lead Generation
- Client Retention
- Feedback Mechanism

Comment: Thanks, but still, many of these items don't seem applicable since the user only needs to connect himself/herself. Further usage of the retrieved data isn't linked to Facebook; so it might even decrease their webtraffic.

Comment: If you are a developer/techy you would realize that facebook is controlling the recent social networking trend. They are leading as Apple does in it's own scope. The points stated above are more or less connected to that frame of leading new ideas and keeping the masses liable. Either as external sources or internal.